# odd NoSuchMethodError when running fat jar

Tags: java, json, hadoop, sbt, sbt-assembly

I have a fat jar with some dependencies that use org.codehaus.jackson libraries for parsing JSON. Here's the error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.readTree([B)Lorg/codehaus/jackson/JsonNode;
```

Looking inside the jar, I can see that method:

```
public JsonNode readTree(byte content[])
    throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
    JsonNode n = (JsonNode)_readMapAndClose(_jsonFactory.createJsonParser(content), JSON_NODE_TYPE);
    return ((JsonNode) (n != null ? n : NullNode.instance));
}
```

The code is run through a 'hadoop jar' command and the jar is built using sbt assembly. The jackson version or core and mapper is 1.9.2, which do include that method.

Running this through 'sbt run' doesn't yield the error and the dependency-graph plugin confirms everything is in place.

What have I overlooked?

Comment: is it not problem caused by older version on jackeson included in a jar on classpath that is loaded before the correct version?

Comment: Is proguard (an obfuscator) involved somewhere?

Comment: I've excluded "org.codehaus.jackson","jackson-mapper-asl" and "org.codehaus.jackson","jackson-core-asl"

Comment: @Trinimon, the is no obfuscator. Perhaps it's a json parsing issue and the exception doesn't include that detail....

Comment: I also suspect multiple versions of jackson in classpath. could you post relevant portion of your build.sbt like `libraryDependencies` and  `mergeStrategy in assembly` so I can try to reproduce this?